# JavaScript Nested Functions cross referencing

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nested-function

I have a nested function that needs a **return type** of the previously declared function to use it as a **function argumen**t . I don't know if my structure is correct or can support this .

would be grateful for some advice on how to call it

```
  var myObject = {
     funct1 : (function (){..... return funct1; })(),
     funct2 : (function (funct1){..... return func2; })(funct1)
     };
```

So the question is how would I call that funct1 argument correctly in the second function

Do I use the myObject.Funct1 or is there another method of calling that object internally ...

Im currently getting a  error

> *Cannot read property 'funct1' of undefined*

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “return type”?

Comment: So function one returns the funct1 object ...

function two needs that object and uses it as an argument . Im not sure how to call it with in the myObject object ...
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this by declaring an object literal since the keys of the object can't be used during the object creation.

You can get the same functionality by doing this, though:

```
const myObject = (() => {
  const func1 = () => 'result of func1';
  const func2 = () => func1() + ' and func2';
  return { func1, func2 }
})();

console.log(myObject.func2()); // result of func1 and func2
```